# Report on Scheduled Reports

Tags: reporting

Is there any way to get a list of all scheduled reports and the schedule they run on? I can get a list of reports under Monitoring > Scheduled Jobs, but that doesn't show me the schedule they run on. I have to click through to the report and then schedule future runs to see the current schedule.

The [CronTrigger](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_crontrigger.htm) object seems to be the closest I can get, but as has been noted in the past, that object doesn't have a name or really any way to identify what Apex class or report is scheduled.

I don't think there is a way based on this [idea on IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HN6u), but hoping someone has some tricks up their sleeve.

Comment: Your post made me curious so I did some searching around my Dev Org this morning. Didn't find anything conclusive, but saw a couple things you might want to explore. One thought was to query off the QueueSobject for CronTrigger__r, etc if QueueSobject is what it sounds like. The others were to query off Document in a similar manner since the reports have to be created and are stored as Documents in Folders. Just a couple ideas that may be worth exploring further...

Comment: Did you try [AsyncApexJob API Object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Winter '14 Release now makes this possible by giving you access to the [CronJobDetail](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/Content/sforce_api_objects_cronjobdetail.htm) object from the [CronTrigger](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/Content/sforce_api_objects_crontrigger.htm) object:

```
SELECT Id, CronJobDetail.Id, CronJobDetail.Name, CronJobDetail.JobType, StartTime, EndTime, CronExpression
FROM CronTrigger
```

Answer (score 0):

The schedules for reports that are scheduled (Subscribed) in lightning can be retrieved using the `/analytics/notifications?source=lightningReportSubscribe` API endpoint.  This includes a `schedule` object like:

```
"schedule": {
  "details": {
    "daysOfWeek": [
      "thu"
    ],
    "time": 9
  },
  "frequency": "weekly"
}
```